# Send user selected filters (parameters) to a data source connection

Tags: tableau-api

I am new to Tableau and am wondering how best to achieve a specific need. Currently, we have a website that is used internally to visualize data. A user is allowed to specify a variety of different filters (date range, group by, column filters, etc) to display the data that they want. The selected filters are passed to an api that gets the requested data from the server and returns only the relevant information to be displayed as a grid or a chart.

What we want to do with Tableau, is setup a Tableau Server where we will publish workbooks that users will be able to see. The part that I can't find the answer to is how to pass user (viewer) specified filters to a web data connector. Everything I have read so far suggests that there is no way to make a dynamic data source and instead I have to publish all data and tableau will handle the filtering, grouping, etc. That might be fine for single days but if a user needs to view a big date range which can have millions of records, it just doesn't seem like the best solution.

So in summary, what is the best way to create a workbook where a viewer can filter and group the data. (First choice is a Web Data connector, second choice is files, and if none work we can also do a database)

Comment: What's powering the datasource? I know in SQL Server custom queries, you can use the workbook's parameters.

Comment: @Andy - Unfortunately all raw data is currently in a bunch of files (one per day) which the data source consumes.